# Trying to create seasons out of months

Tags: r

```
month=c(1:12)
```

I am trying to set up seasons but cant get winter as it is dec, jan, feb.

i have summer as

```
summer=month[6:8]
```

and the rest of the seasons working.

I have tried

```
winter= month[1:12] ; winter= month[1:2,12] , winter= month[1,2,12]
```

and a few other variations. thanks

Comment: `month[c(12,1:2)]` - you need to join the values with `c()`

Comment: Code formatting tip: you want 3 backticks, or indent by 4 spaces, not single quote marks.

Comment: @thelatemail inside the brackets, thank you

Comment: @neilfws hey thanks

Comment: Winter starts `dec 22nd` if you are in the northern hemisphere while it starts on June 21 in the southern hemisphere. So Its intirely not true to claim that whole of dec is winter. Rather March can be winter since winter ends on 21st March. So are you taking the date into consideration or just want the months? if so should March be winter? More than 2/3 of the month is winter

Comment: @Onyambu Yeah its not the most important aspect, just for generalization of points for plotting.